# Serialize map in Ros2

Tags: ros, navigation, ros2, mapping, serialization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am navigating with an omnidirectional agv (ros2 foxy) and I want to use Slam localization mode while doing that. In detail I am using slam_toolbox with online_async mode at the moment.
Is there a tutorial on how to use the serialization service to serialize the map I created while driving. Or whats the command, so I can use this map to localize on?

I used `ros2 run nav2_map_server map_saver_cli -f /path/to/map`to save the map but as far as I understand these map files (.yaml and .pgm) aren't meant to localize on. I have to serialize the map to be able to use it with slam_toolbox again because than i get the files: .posegraph and .data right?

Please correct me if this is not correct.

Thanks in advance, have a great day!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362468/serialize-map-in-ros2/) by [pfedom](https://answers.ros.org/users/53854/pfedom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2020-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The is correct, you need to use the provided serialization services (or rviz tool if you like) to serialize the data for use later in localization or continuing slam sessions.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0